# Цвет бордера у инпута

Tags: html

Написал условие: если в инпуте пусто - то бордер красный. Но я не знаю, какого цвета дефолтовый бордер. Как написать, чтобы поставил какой был (системный-дефолтовый)??

Answer (score 2):

Управляйте стилями с помощью классов. Создайте класс для пустого инпута, и для пустых ставьте его, для заполненных убирайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
  element.style.borderColor=''.
<input type="text"  onkeyup="aa(this)" />
<script>
function aa(element){
    if(element.value==''){
        element.style.borderColor='red';
        }
    else{
        element.style.borderColor=''
        }   
    }
```

Comment: hardcoding mustdie